# How to get all user selected lines with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, execcommand

I have this code but it gave me only the last selected line!

```js
$('#getLine').click(function(){
    console.clear();
    $('div').css('color','');
    
    document.execCommand('formatblock', false, 'div');
    var line=window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
    $(line).css('color','red')
    console.log(line);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editable" contenteditable="TRUE">I am a line<div>I am a new line</div><div>I am the last line</div></div>
<br/>
<input id="getLine" value="Get Line" type="button">
```

How to get all selected lines **even if it was partially selected** ?
I saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text) but I don't want selected text only I want to wrap HTML of this lines to change their styles together.

Comment: FYI there is very little jQuery in that answer.

Comment: I saw this solution but I don't want selected text only I want to wrap HTML of this lines to change their styles together.

Comment: For example, suppose I need to change the selected lines "Line-height".

Comment: So you changed your question to not get the selection but act on it? Did you read the documentation for [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

Comment: I've changed my question to be more understandable.Yes, I've read it. I asked this question because I had a problem that I can not solve it by reading this documentation.

Comment: OK I found an alternative and don't need to answer of this question. Thank you!